# move mailitem to sent items

Tags: vba, outlook, move, mailitem

When responding to emails on a website, I receive a copy of my replies back to my inbox.  I am creating code that will update my Outlook inbox and show the original inquiry as being replied to, and then move my reply to the "Sent Items" folder.  All of the code works except it will not move the mailitem to the "Sent Items" folder.  I'm not sure if the "Sent Items" is a restricted folder, or where I have gone wrong.  My code is below:

```
'locate the imap folder rather than the default outlook folder
 Set oFolder= Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(myIMAPFolder)
 Set oInbox = oFolder.Folders("Inbox")

 'sort the inbox based on the time received to find the most recent mail with  a matching subject and sender
 Set MyItems = oInbox.Items
 MyItems.Sort "ReceivedTime", True
 i = 0
 Do
     i = i + 1
     sSearch = Mid(m.Subject, 5, 100)
     Set oReply = MyItems(i)
 Loop Until oReply.Subject = sSearch And oReply.SenderEmailAddress = m.Recipients(1).Address

 'add the reply icon to the mail in the inbox and mark the original message as being read
 With oReply
     .PropertyAccessor.SetProperty "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x10800003", 261 'standard replied icon
      .UnRead = False
      .Save
  End With

  'move my incoming message to the "Sent Items Folder" & mark as being read
  '**** THIS SECTION OF CODE DOESN'T WORK??? ****
  Set oSent = oFolder.Folders("Sent Items")
  With m
      .Move (oSent)
      .UnRead = False
      .Save
  End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Move is a function that returns the new item. The old item must be immediately released. There is no need to call Save

```
Set oSent = oFolder.Folders("Sent Items")
m = m.Move(Set)
```